# python how to replace string by regex group?

Tags: python, regex

Give an string like `'/apps/platform/app/app_name/etc'`, I can use

`p = re.compile('/apps/(?P<p1>.*)/app/(?P<p2>.*)/')`

to get two matched groups of `platform` and `app_name`, but how can I use `re.sub` function (or maybe better way) to replace those two groups with other string like `windows` and `facebook`? So the final string would like `/apps/windows/app/facebook/etc`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a regex and not [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for this?

Comment: @NPE I have no idea about the relationship between string replace and `os.path`. but maybe you can show me some code:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate group replacement wouldn't be possible through regex. So i suggest you to do like this.

```
(?<=/apps/)(?P<p1>.*)(/app/)(?P<p2>.*)/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rZ2uV3/2)

Then replace the matched characters with `windows\2facebook/` . And also i suggest you to define your regex as raw string. Lookbehind is used inorder to avoid extra capturing group.

```
>>> s = '/apps/platform/app/app_name/etc'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=/apps/)(?P<p1>.*)(/app/)(?P<p2>.*)/', r'windows\2facebook/', s)
'/apps/windows/app/facebook/etc'
```